# How to screw drywall ceiling with furring

Tags: drywall, ceiling, joists

I am adding a drywall ceiling to my basement, and it already has 1x3 furring spaced 12" apart. I am planning on using ½x4x8 drywall sheets.

When screwing my drywall, is it best to screw only in the furring using 1¼ (or longer?) screws, or also screw in the joists when possible using longer screws?

The current furring has only one nail per joist, should I add another to have two per joist or is one enough?

Comment: Are you using 1/2" xd or cd for fireproofing or just standard 1/2"?  1 1/4 should be fine after all unless you are marking the insection of the furring and joist you are likely going to only be hitting the furring most of the time.  I'd back the nail up with a screw are the current nails spiral, I am not sure I'd trust nails where the force is pulling inline with shaft of the nail.

Comment: I'm using standard 1/2. So if I understand correctly screwing only in the furring is enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to use too long a screw. Definitely do not screw into the joist. The joist expands and contracts as the humidity and temperature changes, but the screw stays relatively (to the wood it's embedded in) still.  The longer the screw is embedded in wood, the greater distance the wood can shrink away from the screw head.  This will cause screw pops, or dimples.  This is especially true if you use adhesive.  The adhesive will pull the drywall with the wood as the wood shrinks, but the screw head will stay stationary.  Use the shortest screw needed to fasten the drywall. 3/4" into wood is fine.

I would throw in an extra fastener or two to fasten the furring to the joist. As far as the weight of the drywall; I know it seems heavy, but you're using a lot of screws.  When you take the weight of the panel and divide by the number of screws you're using, it doesn't seem that heavy at all.

Comment: Thanks for the  answer! I would upvote if I could! Just one more quick question, my furring is 3/4 thick, If I use 1¼ screws with 1/2 drywall, they might go all the way through the furring is that bad? Should I go for 1" screws instead?

Comment: 1 1/4 inch is fine.  Don't want to go longer than that.  Of course, make sure you get the course threaded ones.  I know it sounds silly to have to say use the drywall screws meant for wood, but in one of my old homes, I found that the "pro" drywallers used fine-threaded screws meant for metal to fasten drywall to the wood trusses. Not cool.